# Modify the Deferred result

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Given an API (implemented by [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)) that returns a model. I wrap an old fashioned [Call](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html) into a `Deferred` using the extention function:

```
fun <T> Call<T>.toDeferred(): Deferred<T> {
    val deferred = CompletableDeferred<T>()

    // cancel request as well
    deferred.invokeOnCompletion {
        if (deferred.isCancelled) {
            cancel()
        }
    }

    enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>?, t: Throwable) {
            deferred.completeExceptionally(t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>?, response: Response<T>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                deferred.complete(response.body()!!)
            } else {
                deferred.completeExceptionally(HttpException(response))
            }
        }
    })

    return deferred
}
```

Now I can get my model like this:

```
data class Dummy(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun getDummy(): Deferred<Dummy> = api.getDummy().toDeferred()
```

But how can I *modify* the object inside the `Deferred` and return a `Deferred`:

```
fun getDummyAge(): Deferred<Int> {
    // return getDummy().age
}
```

I'm new to coroutines so may be this is not how the things get done here. Assuming I'm an [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) fan I'd implement this case like:

```
fun getDummy(): Single<Dummy> = api.getDummy().toSingle()

fun getDummyAge(): Single<Int> = getDummy().map { it.age }
```

So should I try to return a `Deferred` from the `getDummyAge` function? Or may be it's better to declare a `suspended fun` whenever possible and call `deferred.await()` on all my api's methods?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you follow *async style* of programming, that is writing functions that return `Deferred<T>`, then you can define *async function* `getDummyAge` like this:

```
fun getDummyAge(): Deferred<Int> = async { getDummy().await().age }
```

However, this style of programming is generally not recommend in Kotlin. The idiomatic Kotlin approach is to define a *suspending extension function* `Call<T>.await()` with the following signature:

```
suspend fun <T> Call<T>.await(): T = ... // more on it later
```

and use it to write *suspending function* `getDummy` that returns a result of `Dummy` type *directly* without wrapping it into a deferred:

```
suspend fun getDummy(): Dummy = api.getDummy().await()
```

In this case you can trivially write *suspending function* `getDummyAge`:

```
suspend fun getDummyAge(): Int = getDummy().age
```

For Retrofit calls you can implement `await` extension like this:

```
suspend fun <T> Call<T>.await(): T = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    cont.invokeOnCompletion { cancel() }
    enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>?, t: Throwable) {
            cont.resumeWithException(t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>?, response: Response<T>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                cont.resume(response.body()!!)
            } else {
                cont.resumeWithException(HttpException(response))
            }
        }
    })
}
```

If you want to learn more on the differences in style between async and suspending functions, then I'd suggest to watch [Introduction to Coroutines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hfBv0a09Jc) from KotlinConf 2017. If you prefer a short read, then [this section from the design document](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#asynchronous-programming-styles) offers some insight, too.

Comment: The approach with *suspending functions* looks better indeed. Thank you for the informative answer

Comment: @NikolayKulachenko You can also use https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-retrofit which already has this extension (and https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter for going the other way and using `Deferred` directly in the Retrofit API).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov They are both neat and lightweight libraries. But I don't want to pull any when I can just write a couple of extention functions instead. Or grab them from the source :)